# Write output in different files for different input files using mapreduce

Tags: file, text, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

How to write output in different files for different input files using mapreduce for example
suppose i want to calculate term frequency of terms per file from video.txt and outlier.txt , store result in video1.txt and oulier1.txt respectively?

Comment: How is your output file currently named? Isn't it part-r-nnnnn?

Comment: Is it ok to write it to local file system or only to HDFS, because we asked that similar question in a hadoop forum, they replied us as we cannot have multiple outputfiles. The best you can do is to have exactly same amount of Reduce workers as the number of different video/outlier and each reduce worker write it on different file

Answer (score 0):

In you mapper append the filename to each word you find. Your key would then be 'word+filename'. Make sure that your partitioner uses the 'filename' for partitioning so that all words from the same file will end up with the same reducer